# How to find most frequent value with respect to row value?

Tags: excel, vba, word-frequency

```
Material    Vendor Code
10000001    10164
10000001    10164
10000001    10164
10000001    56394
10000001    10164
10000001    10164
10000001    10164
10000001    10164
10000001    10164
10000001    10164
10000001    10164
10000001    10164
10000002    10164
10000006    56394
10000006    10222
10000006    10222
10000006    10222
10000006    10222
10000006    10222
10000006    10222
10000006    10222
10000006    10222
10000006    10222
10000006    10222
10000006    10222
10000006    10222
10000006    10222
10000006    10222
10000006    10222
```

hi everyone, i have the following data. I want to add another column like "Most Frequent Vendor".

For example, for material 10000001 it is 10164.

How can I do it? I couldn't find it, searching for 2 hours. It is a simple thing but couldn't make us of pivot charts, frequency function etc. A vba approach would be much more better since I am editing all the data with vba. Thanks in advance!

Comment: "A vba code would be much more better" - then why not try writing one?

Comment: Does this work: `=INDEX(B1:B29,MAX(COUNTIF(A1:A29,10000001)))`. B1:B29 is your vendor code, and A1:A29 is the Material. Change the final `10000001` to whatever you're looking for.

Comment: it doesn't work, it just brings the value at top. It founds 56394 for 10000006 it should be 10222

Comment: @BruceWayne you need to put it in a MATCH and the COUNTIFS needs to include the values in Column B.  `=INDEX(B1:B29,MATCH(MAX(COUNTIFS(A1:A29,10000001,B1:B29,B1:B29)),COUNTIFS(A1:A29,10000001,B1:B29,B1:B29),0))` as an array formula, confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following array formula will return what you want:

```
=INDEX(B1:B30,MATCH(MAX(COUNTIFS(A1:A30,$E$3,B1:B30,B1:B30)),COUNTIFS(A1:A30,$E$3,B1:B30,B1:B30),0))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

Comment: no it doesn't work. When I change the $E$3 to A2 for example, it gives N/A

Comment: Did you confirm it with Ctrl-Shift-Enter after the edit? Did you replace both $E$3

Comment: how can i find the second most frequent?

Comment: That is a new question and it involves replacing the MAX with LARGE and the k being 2.  Do some research on that, the formula does not change much just replacing the MAX with LARGE.  If you get stuck come back and ask a new question.